# Does protobuf-net have built-in compression for serialization?

Tags: serialization, protobuf-net, binary-serialization

I was doing some comparison between `BinaryFormatter` and protobuf-net serializer and was quite pleased with what I [found](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/08/performance-test-binaryformatter-vs-protobuf-net/), but what was strange is that protobuf-net managed to serialize the objects into a smaller byte array than what I would get if I just wrote the value of every property into an array of bytes without any metadata.

I know protobuf-net supports string interning if you set `AsReference` to `true`, but I'm not doing that in this case, so does protobuf-net provide some compression by default?

Here's some code you can run to see for yourself:

```cs
var simpleObject = new SimpleObject
                       {
                           Id = 10,
                           Name = "Yan",
                           Address = "Planet Earth",
                           Scores = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList()
                       };

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memStream);
    // 4 bytes for int
    binaryWriter.Write(simpleObject.Id);      
    // 3 bytes + 1 more for string termination
    binaryWriter.Write(simpleObject.Name);    
    // 12  bytes + 1 more for string termination
    binaryWriter.Write(simpleObject.Address); 
    // 40 bytes for 10 ints
    simpleObject.Scores.ForEach(binaryWriter.Write); 

    // 61 bytes, which is what I expect
    Console.WriteLine("BinaryWriter wrote [{0}] bytes",
      memStream.ToArray().Count());
}

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(memStream, simpleObject);

    // 41 bytes!
    Console.WriteLine("Protobuf serialize wrote [{0}] bytes",
      memStream.ToArray().Count());
}
```

EDIT: forgot to add, the `SimpleObject` class looks like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class SimpleObject
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public List<int> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No it does not; there is no "compression" as such specified in the protobuf spec; however, it does (by default) use "varint encoding" - a variable-length encoding for integer data that means small values use less space; so 0-127 take 1 byte plus the header. Note that varint *by itself* goes pretty loopy for negative numbers, so "zigzag" encoding is also supported which allows small *magnitude* numbers to be small (basically, it interleaves positive and negative pairs).

Actually, in your case for `Scores` you should also look at "packed" encoding, which requires either `[ProtoMember(4, IsPacked = true)]` or the equivalent via `TypeModel` in v2 (v2 supports either approach). This avoids the overhead of a header per value, by writing a single header and the *combined* length. "Packed" can be used with varint/zigzag. There are also fixed-length encodings for scenarios where you *know* the values are likely large and unpredictable.

Note also: but if your data has lots of text you may benefit from additionally running it through gzip or deflate; if it *doesn't*, then both gzip and deflate could cause it to get bigger.

An overview of the wire format [is here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding); it isn't very tricky to understand, and may help you plan how best to further optimize.

Comment: Why does protobuf make 1 byte only for the 128 values? 8 bits allows to write 256 different values.

Comment: @tobi it uses "varint" encoding for the field number - which means 7 bits payload, and 1 bit "there's another byte to read". You keep reading until the MSB is zero.

Answer (score 0):

At least the c++ library does support writing to and from compressed streams:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.h

I'm not sure though if that has been ported to the .Net implementation.

Comment: in .NET, you'd just connect any serializer to a [`GZipStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netcore-3.1) instance, and: you're done